# Possible to nest outputUI and renderUI in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to move conditional panels from the `ui` section to the `server` section by wrapping the conditional panels in a `renderUI` function. I am doing this in order to eliminate the flashing of other items when invoking the App before settling on the conditional panels. I tried this on a simpler App and this does this trick. However when I try it on the MWE code posted here, I get an error message. What´s more complicated about this MWE is that one of the conditional panels I'm moving to `renderUI` already calls on another `renderUI`. I assumed it would be possible to nest `outputUI`/`renderUI`. Is there any way to make this work?

Below are 2 code examples. The first MWE works as it should (except for the flashing of other things before settling on conditional panel - which moving to `renderUI` should resolve). The second set of code below reflects my attempt to move the conditional panels from `ui` to `server` using `renderUI`.

Working MWE:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)                                     
  b <- seq(1:x)                                     
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)                     
  return(c)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1"),
      conditionalPanel(
          condition="input.tabselected==2",
          sliderInput('periods','Input periods:',min=1,max=120,value=60),
          matrix1.input("base_input"),
          useShinyjs(),
          actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn','Show'), 
          actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn','Hide'),
          actionButton('resetPerfVectorBtn','Reset'),
          hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))
      ) # close conditional panel
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("About",value=1),
        tabPanel("Dynamic",value=2,plotOutput("graph1")), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  periods        <-  reactive(input$periods)
  base_input     <-  reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input   <-  reactive(input$vector_input)

  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2))})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetPerfVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix1.input("Plot"))
    }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
 
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showPerfVectorBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]))
    else plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])))
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Crashing code where I try moving conditional panels from `ui` to `server` using `renderUI` (defined functions `matrix1.input` and `vector.base` not shown below for sake of brevity, they are shown in the MWE code above):

```
ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("Panels")
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("About",value=1),
        tabPanel("Dynamic",value=2,plotOutput("graph1")), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  periods        <-  reactive(input$periods)
  base_input     <-  reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input   <-  reactive(input$vector_input)
  
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2))})
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1")
    conditionalPanel(
      condition="input.tabselected==2",
      sliderInput('periods','Input periods:',min=1,max=120,value=60),
      matrix1.input("base_input"),
      useShinyjs(),
      actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn','Show'), 
      actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn','Hide'),
      actionButton('resetPerfVectorBtn','Reset'),
      hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))
    ) # close seconds conditional panel
  })

  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetPerfVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix1.input("Plot"))
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showPerfVectorBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]))
    else plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])))
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to nest `outputUI`/`renderUI` in R shiny. Resolved code below does this. See how `output$Vectors` is nested inside of `output$Panels`, both using `renderUI` in the `server` section.

The objective of all this moving around of code was to eliminate the rapid flashing of all `ui` items when first invoking the App, making it appear sloppy, buggy, unprofessional. The moving of conditional panels from the `ui` to the `server` section, using `outputUI` in the `ui` section of code and `renderUI` in the `server` section, has eliminated the flashing-by of all `ui` items when first invoking the App.

Below is the final resolved code. The "crashing code" above didn't work because the conditional panels, in the `renderUI` section under `server`, needed to be wrapped in `tagList` as shown below. An accidental omission. Also, the above crashing code was also crashing because the `observeEvent` for `updateMatrixInput` also needed to wrapped in `renderUI` (with respect to this last item, I'm not sure why this worked - I came by it through trial and error and a hunch. I hope this doesn't lead to another problem down the road - usually what happens when I implement a "fix" that I don't 100% understand).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)                                     
  b <- seq(1:x)                                     
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)                     
  return(c)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("Panels")
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("About",value=1),
        tabPanel("Dynamic",value=2,plotOutput("graph1")), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  periods        <-  reactive(input$periods)
  base_input     <-  reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input   <-  reactive(input$vector_input)

  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        sliderInput('periods','Input periods:',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn','Show'), 
        actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn','Hide'),
        actionButton('resetPerfVectorBtn','Reset'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors")),
      ) # close conditional panel
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetPerfVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix1.input("Plot"))
  }) # close render UI
 
  # run observeEvent in renderUI
  renderUI({ 
    observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
      updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input",
                        value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2))})
  }) # close renderUI
    
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showPerfVectorBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]))
    else plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])))
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```